# Reducing Local Neighbourhood of pixels

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I have recently come across a problem that I cannot seem to solve. I have a processed image that contains a number of pixels spread out across the entire image in small 'local' groups. I would like to find the 'centre' as it were of each group and place a single pixel in the output image as a representative of each group. The groupings can either be a closely knit group with no pixel zero spacing between them or a smaller spread out group with only a few (less than 4~5 pixels) between them. My first thought was to use something along the lines of morphological erosion but this doesn't account for the case of slightly more spread out groups of pixels. I would just like to know if someone can point me in the right direction. The following is an example of what I would like to do:
[image: Local Group]
The left hand side image shows the input (the big black dot represents a group of pixels with no zeroes between them) and the right hand side image is an example of the type of output or processed image I would like to have. Finally I am using MATLAB and it can be assumed that the input image is a binary image (either with black being 1 or 0 either way the logic should be the same).

Thanks so much for your help!

EDIT: Thanks everyone for their input - I will be trying out the different solutions over the next day or so and I will try to reply to everyone whence I'm done. Thank you all so much for your insightful inputs - it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can the clusters always be grouped using a uniform rectangular grid, as in the example image? If so, do you know how much apart they are?

Comment: Is there a hard boundary on how far apart the points have to be before they are considered to be in different clusters?  Are the clusters always circular or could you have oblong clusters?

Comment: Sorry the clusters are randomly spread out and not always in a grid-like grouping as above. Well I didn't make it perfectly clear in the post above then but pixels that are more than 5 pixels away from another can be considered a separate cluster. Furthermore the clusters of pixels can assume any shape - they are just a collection of pixels at roundabout the same place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend an approach involving morphological closing followed by connected component analysis. Note that I've inverted the problem so the "good dots" are high-valued and the "bad background" is black. This fits more closely with the expected definition of the morphological operations.

```
path = 'yourimage.png'
space = 5; % you can change this to make it accept bigger spacings

input = imcomplement(rgb2gray(imread(path))) > 0;
input = imclose(input, strel('disk', space));
[labels, num] = bwlabel(input, 8);
output = logical(zeros(size(input)));
for i = 1:num
   [r, c] = find(labels==i); 
   x = round(mean(c))
   y = round(mean(r))
   output(y,x) = 1;
end

imshow(output)
```

The results look like this:

[image: Results]

Seems to me to be what you're looking for!

Comment: I think this answer leads in the wrong direction. As pointed out by slayton, this is a clustering problem and should be solved as one.

Comment: I disagree -- I believe this is still a clustering solution. It may not use k-means or a hierarchical approach directly, but the algorithm is definitely performing clustering. The magic really takes place inside the `bwlabel` connected component portion. It's doing clustering! The only parameter you're providing is a measure of the cluster scale. I still think it's an elegant solution to the problem as proposed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your excellent reply. This is a simple route and require no adaption to work on my (lower) end pc. I believe yours and slayton's answers are two sides of the same coin - both are 'clustering' as it were but his is grounded in higher dimensional datasets (and not just images). I like your solution as it is the simplest and works for my situation (as well as scaling well for larger images with more data points).

Comment: @user901898 Thanks! Feel free to mark it as "the answer" if it solves your problem ;)

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are describing is generally referred to as [clustering or cluster analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis). Its can be quite difficult depending on your data set and your analysis constraints. However, in your case it is simple because you have a hard threshold (5 pixels) to use.

Aardvarkk has already put out a great solution but it doesn't really demonstrate the process of clustering.  Here is a very simple way you could cluster your data and get more or less the same result.

1. Compute the pairwise distance between your points. For N points this results in an NxN matrix
2. Threshold that matrix
3. Iterate through the rows of the matrix

Each iteration would look like the following:

- if `i` is already clustered, continue
- if `i` isn't in a cluster, create a new cluster and assign `i` to it
- find all other points that are close to `i` (columns in row `i` that are equal to 1)
- Check to see if any of those points are already in a cluster
- If yes set `i` and all points close to `i` to the minimum cluster id
- If no set `i` and all points close to `i` to `i's` cluster

Here is a quick example I whipped up:

```
%Generate random points
nPts = 300;
clustId = zeros(nPts,1);
clusterCount = 0;
x = randi(3, [1, nPts])*10+ randn(1, nPts);
y = randi(3, [1, nPts])*10 + randn(1, nPts);

%Compute the distance matrix  from http://goo.gl/8mAoC
dist = distance([x;y], [x;y]);

maxDist = 5;
binDist = dist <= maxDist;


for i = 1:nPts
    % if this point is already clustered skip it
    if clustId(i) ~= 0
        continue;
    end

    %if the current point isn't in a cluster, create a new cluster and add
    %the point to that cluster
    if clustId(i) == 0
        clusterCount = clusterCount+1;
        clustId(i) = clusterCount;
        fprintf('New point, creating cluster:%d\n', clusterCount);
    end

    % get the indices of the points that collide with the i
    idx = binDist(:,i);

    % check to see if idx contains points that already belong to another clustered
    % if it doesn't collisionIdx will be equal to i
    collisionIdx = idx & clustId>0;

    %get the smallest cluster from collisionIdx
    mergeClustId = min(clustId(collisionIdx));

    %assing all the original points to that cluster
    clustId(idx) = mergeClustId;
end
```

Simply iterate through the cluster Ids to calculate the centroids:

```
cx = [];
cy = [];
for i = 1:clusterCount
    idx = clustId == i;
    cx(i) = mean(x(idx));
    cy(i) = mean(y(idx));
end
```

Then plot the results with:

```
figure; 
plot(cx,cy,'c.', 'markersize', 50); hold on;
plot(x,y,'.');
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the excellent reply. I wish to ask a few questions: first and foremost how do you get the centroid of your clusters? Secondly I believe yours and aardvark's solutions are much the same the only difference being yours is adaptable to multiple dimensions whereas his isn't (as yours is grounded in cluster analysis of which I have done some work in). My question is given the simplicity of my situation (just an image) is it really necessary to cluster the data and NOT go for the connected-component route? One other thing: I had to adapt your solution to use bsxfun (memory constraints).

Comment: Just a continuation to give a better explanation of my last point: I don't have the very newest of PC's and the distance function given in the note you made would not run on my system. I just used the bsx function to perform the same calculation (a trick I learnt that allows me to do larger matrix multiplications on my system). Your solution is perfect, its obviously just something I had to change on my end (and will only become a bigger problem for much larger images). Just something to note as why I feel the other solution is more appropriate.

Comment: @user901898 I've added the code I used to calculate the cluster centers and the plotting code.

Comment: @user901898 no its not necessary to cluster the data. I would probably use the method put forth by aardvarkk to solve your exact problem. However if I wanted are more general solution I'd do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could use a region growing method first to joing the clstered pixels and then use erosion. That would work, if you know, that the distances between the clusters are larger than the clusters themselves. Maybe use center of gravity to determine the middle of each blob after the region growing.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by slayton, this is a clustering problem.

As the separation of your clusters is very clear you could use a simple graph-based approach. If you have access to a graph algorithm library (such as [boost::graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html), for which many bindings exist) the following approach should be pretty straightforward:

1. Build a complete graph of your points with edge weights as distances.
2. Compute a minimum spanning tree, for example with [Prims algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm)
3. Eliminate edges exceeding a length threshold from the tree
4. Find the remaining connected components

Comment: For that to work you need a global distance threshold, where every pair of points closer than that distance will be grouped in the same cluster, right? If so, what's the difference to the morphological algorithm @aardvarkk suggested?

Comment: The difference is probably more a theoretical than a practical one. IMHO the problem is inherently a clustering one and not an image processing one, and it should be solved in the right domain.

Comment: I really don't see the theoretical difference between solving a clustering problem using a tree algorithm or using a morphological algorithm.

Comment: For example, a tree algorithm does not presuppose a grid, so it allows real-valued data. It generalizes nicely and efficiently to higher dimensions and alternative distance metrics. Also, a graph approach is the basis for more advanced techniques like spectral clustering. Of course, this is probably not terribly important for the question.